# Relation between $\max$-norm and $1$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ square matrix, and

$$\|A\|_1 := \max_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |A_{i,j}|$$

and

$$\|A\|_{\max} := \max_{i,j} |A_{i,j}|$$

1. Does $\|A\|_1 \le 1$ imply that $\|A\|_{\max} \le 1$?
2. Is there any relation between $\|A\|_1$ and $\|A\|_{\max}$?

Comment: @Bungo I misread the definition of $\|A\|_{\max}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$|A_{i,j}|\leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}|A_{i,j}|,$$
for each $1\leq j \leq n$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|A_{i,j}|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|A_{i,j}|=
n \max_{1\leq i\leq n}|A_{i,j}|$$
Therefore

$$ \max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |A_{i,j}|\leq n\max_{1\leq i,j\leq n} |A_{i,j}|.$$ That is

$$ \|A\|_{1}\leq n \|A\|_{\infty}.\qquad (1)$$

The estimate (1) is sharp. Meaning the factor $n$ cannot be replaced by a smaller positive constant. To see this consider the matrix $A$ with $A_{i,j}=1$ for which (1) is actually an equality.

Now, does  $\|A\|_{1}$ control $\|A\|_{\infty}$ ?

We have that
$$\max_{1\leq i\leq n} |A_{i,j}|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} |A_{i,j}|\Longrightarrow 
\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\max_{1\leq i\leq n} |A_{i,j}|\leq \max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |A_{i,j}|$$
So, it is true that

$$ \|A\|_{\infty}\leq  \|A\|_{1}\qquad (2)$$

Again the constant one in (2) is sharp. When  $A=I_{n}$, the unit matrix, we have an equality in (2).